# Slow queries for statistics with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a statistics page that handles a load of data. The problem is that when query a big range of data (1 year) it renders for ages (> 25 sec) and often reaches the max execution time (30 seconds).

What is the most common workaround in cases like that?

Comment: About what data are we talking here and what is the granularity of the data (days, hours, minutes, seconds, ...)? Do you aggregate your data when the user wants a statistic for a long time frame?

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not relevant to Eloquent, you need to optimize your query's by explaining them, for example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `users`
```

2) research on how to build indexes and candidate keys, that will improve your execution time.

3) use a cached query like Memcached.